# Get SAML metadata from Azure AD B2C to set up a circle of trust with an identity provider

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm unable to get the metadata out of Azure AD B2C needed to set up a circle of trust with a SAML2 identity provider. The URL I found to get the metadata generates a runtime error.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/<tenantName>.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1a<policyName>/Samlp/metadata
```

Replace `<tenantName>` with your tenant and `<policyName>` with your policy name.

Does anyone know what the correct URL or possible problem is?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SAML metadata uri is missing the technical provider of the SAML IDP in your custom policy.
Try this uri:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/<tenantName>.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_<policyName>/samlp/metadata?idptp=<SAML IDP Technical Profile>
```

Regards